# Cannot use WebDriverExceptionEventArgs.ThrownException in Selenium C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, exception

I am encountering a problem trying to use WebDriverExceptionEventArgs.ThrownException:

```cs
firingWebDriver.ExceptionThrown     += new EventHandler<WebElementEventArgs>(_ExceptionThrown);

static void _ExceptionThrown(object sender, WebElementEventArgs e)
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.ThrownException.Message);
        //Console.WriteLine(e.ThrownException.Message);
    }
```

However VS2015 displays the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler<OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events.WebElementArgs> to 'System.EventHandler<OpenaQA.Selenium.Support.Events.WebDriverExceptionEventArgs>
```

I am not sure where the mistake lies, any help?

Comment: The exception event handler should be of type `WebDriverExceptionEventArgs` not `WebElementEventArgs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kate Paulk commented, the solution was to change `WebElementEventArgs` to `WebDriverExceptionEventArgs`, like so:

```cs
firingWebDriver.ExceptionThrown     += new EventHandler<WebDriverExceptionEventArgs>(_ExceptionThrown);

static void _ExceptionThrown(object sender, WebDriverExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    //System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.ThrownException.Message);
    //Console.WriteLine(e.ThrownException.Message);
}
```